# How to make SWF file not auto play

Tags: flash

Does anyone know how I can make this SWF file not autoplay? when play=true, it autoplays. When play=false, I get a blank screen.

You can test it at

http://abdullahyahya.com/temp/testswf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWF files are not videos, they don't just autoplay or not. You should set a `stop()` action on the first frame of the SWF if you would like it to expect user input before playing.

See this question for more info: [How to make an embedded video not autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399370/flash-how-to-make-an-embedded-video-not-autoplay)