# Prevent embedded HTML video from autoplaying

Tags: html, video, embed

Here is my code:

```
<object id="flashObj" width="640" height="390" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
   <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isSlim=0" />
   <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
   <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=3945004669001&playerID=2868544859001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAABvZFMzE~,IXjx0MpOF0rs6Zj6tTY84DVV4TqsG9K-&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
   <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
   <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
   <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
   <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isSlim=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=3945004669001&playerID=2868544859001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAABvZFMzE~,IXjx0MpOF0rs6Zj6tTY84DVV4TqsG9K-&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="640" height="390" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" swLiveConnect="true" allowScriptAccess="always" pluginspage=http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash></embed>
</object>
```

What code do I need to add, or how can I otherwise prevent this from autoplaying?

Comment: You might want to find another video, which isn't Flash depending.

Comment: How about format that code so that it's not on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like adding `flashvars="play=false"`

However whether that will work or not depends on a number of different unknowns.

Check out [How to make an embedded video not autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399370/how-to-make-an-embedded-video-not-autoplay) The first answer gives a far better explaination of it than I can.

However personally if this were a problem I were facing, assuming there was nothing stopping me from doing it I would use HTML5's video tag convert the desired video to MP4 and use it that way 
Check out W3cshools for more info on HTML 5 video http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

I hope that helps !